# Use count of unrelated table in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

I have this query:

```
select skill.name, IFNULL(Round(((SUM(ROUND((student_skills.value/skill.value)*100,0)))/82),0),0) as successRate from skill left JOIN student_skills on skill.id = student_skills.skill_id group by skill.name
```

This query returns exactly what I want but I need to replace constant 82 (just for example) with number of rows in table **user** (something like COUNT(user.name)).

Problem is that **use**r is not related to **skill** or **student_skill** table in any way.

How should I alter my query so that it would use current count of users?

Thanks

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: Why not use Select Count(*) from Users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery

```
select skill.name, 
       IFNULL(Round(((SUM(ROUND((student_skills.value/skill.value)*100,0)))/(select COUNT(*) from user)),0),0) as successRate 
from skill 
left JOIN student_skills on skill.id = student_skills.skill_id 
group by skill.name
```